# Micropython: How to free up all RAM memory on startup

Tags: esp8266, micropython

I'm using a library that doesn't free up all memory when the program is stopped. As a result I get an ENOMEM exception when restarting the program. Is there a way to free all RAM memory upon program restart?

For now I'm using hard-reset as a work-around, but I'd like to be able to just stop and restart the program and have it clean up the RAM at startup. Something like: `clean_ram()`. `clean_ram()` would force the garbage collector to free all allocated memory.

Comment: Can you explain what 'restarting the program' means practically? Is it started from the REPL by running a main function or so?

Comment: yes, exactly... I'm using uPycraft to do that...

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to restart the MicroPython interpreter itself on the C level. Exit the Python program and do the whole interpreter setup again.

On Python level, you can manually "unimport" all modules and then call GC:

```py
# main.py
# do not use any global imports here, except builtins
import gc, sys

while True:
    import program

    del program

    for key in sys.modules:
        del sys.modules[key]

    gc.collect()
```

then in `program.py` do whatever you wanted to do in `main`.